# Array 2d VBA optional Element

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array

How can I add an optional element in a 2d array in VBA? Working example:

```
sub test
   Dim arr As Variant, ix as variant
   arr = Array( _
   Array("01probe", 1, 2, True), _
   Array("02datum", 3, 4) _
  )
  '... lots more
  ' true optional, nothing or just "false" as alternative

  For Each ix In arr
   Debug.Print ix(3) '<---- index out of range
  Next ix
end sub
```

Thanks all

Comment: For clarification I didn't down-vote, but may I ask what are you trying to achieve? I mean why not a custom object where you can access its properties individually and then have an array of that object?

Comment: With `array` it might be simpler instead of an object. At present I fill the inner 4th element with `false` if not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is not a 2D type. It is an array of arrays (a jagged array)...

But I cannot imagine why an optional parameter would be necessary.

If your array is declared `As Variant` it may keep any type of variable, objects included. It is not necessary to declare its dimensions, neither. Everything can be considered `Optional`...

See the next code, please:

```
Sub testOptionalArray()
 Dim arr As Variant, dbInteger As Integer, strProbeNr As Long, rng As Range
 Dim rng2 As Range, dbDate As Date, dDate As Date
 
  dbInteger = 11: strProbeNr = 1000: dbDate = Date + 1: dDate = Now
  Set rng = Range("A1:A2"): Set rng2 = Range("B1:B2")
  arr = Array( _
        Array("01probe", dbInteger, strProbeNr, rng), _
        Array("02datum", dbDate, dDate, rng2))
        
  Debug.Print arr(0)(1), arr(0)(3).cells(1, 1).value
  Debug.Print arr(1)(1), arr(1)(UBound(arr(1))).cells.count, arr(1)(UBound(arr(1))).Address
End Sub
```

**Edited, after you posted your code returning an error**:

The code in discussion has to be understood in the next way. Firstly, it would be a good habit to **always** appropriately declare all variables...

```
Sub testJaggedArray()
Dim arr As Variant, ix As Variant
   arr = Array( _
   Array("01probe", 1, 2, True), _
   Array("02datum", 3, 4))
  'The above array must be understood like an array of two arrays, 
  'first of them having 4 elements (ubound = 4, because it starts from 0)
  ' and a second one with only 3 elements.

  For Each ix In arr
   'When your code tries to print the fourth element of an array with only 
   'three elements, of course VBA return 'subscript out of range'.
   Debug.Print ix(3) '<---- subscript out of range
  Next ix
  'You can return an element of an array inside a jagged array in this way:
   Debug.Print arr(1)(ubound(arr(1)))' which means returning of the last element
                                     ' of the second array without returning an error
  'You may use an array of two arrays having different number of element, 
  'but you cannot expect to an array to return an INEXISTENT item.
  'There is no any connection between an hypothetical need of OPTIONAL element.
  'It is only a matter of EXISTING element...
End Sub
```

Comment: The array is declared as variant. You did not get my point, I want to leave out rng2. The reason to not fill the optional parameter is laziness.`Everything can be optional`: No, I get `index out of range` in a `foreach`.

Comment: @Timo : Where do you get "index out of range"? Trying my above code?

Comment: @Timo : Try to better emphasize 'your point', please. English is not my best point and I must admit that I maybe missed something. So, can you clarify the issue, please? And I would also like you to also clarify "index out of range" issue... "Everything can be **CONSIDERED** optional". Not everything can be optional! **No optional parameter is admitted for a VBA array**.

Comment: @Timo : Would I ask too much if I would suggest you to edit your question and share the `foreach` code where you receive the above mentioned error?

Comment: FAneDuru, congrats for the first 10 k

Comment: @Timo : Thanks!  But coming back to your question, can you clarify the above mentioned issues? I can admit that it would not be impossible to miss your point. That's why, can you better define it, please? If not interested to do that, I will not have a problem, too...

Comment: FaneDuro, I have edited my question. If there is no optional parameter permitted for an array, I got the solution: I have to add `false` as the last element if it is not `true`.

Comment: @Timo :I am not sure you understand the meaning of the code you run... It is not a matter of `Optional` parameter. You are dealing with a jagged array and your code **tries printing an inexistent array element**. I will edit the above answer and try explaining...

Comment: @Timo : Doesn't the above code answer your question? Even if it does not confirm your supposition about the Optional parameter necessity...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of FaneDuru I got the solution to loop an array with different inner array sizes without an error:

```
sub test
Dim arr As Variant, i as integer
arr = Array( _
Array("01probe", 1, 2, True), _
Array("02datum", 3, 4) _
)

'... lots more

 For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Debug.Print (arr(i)(UBound(arr(i))))
Next i
end sub
```